# Critical communications during product roll outs

Tags: team-management, communication, tracking, roll-out

My current project is to roll-out a new technology product throughout my company.
 I want to come up with a website that will give a high level insight to the roll-out. I don't know how should I do this or what content should I consider in putting up there! I am thinking on the lines of having some kind of a interface between my team and the customers(end users) regarding the whole roll-out phase, like what is coming, how is it going to be different, what are the expectations from the customers, incentives to go this path, tracking the progress of roll-out, things like this.
I wonder how do the big companies do it when they are about to roll-out a big product or something.

So, I have a new product and am looking for content ideas to put up on the web-site to capture the whole roll-out process.

Comment: Hi camelbrush, welcome to PMSE! I'm afraid I can't see what's the question in place. What's the specific problem you're facing in your company to motivate you to build up a website?

Comment: So, I have a new product and am looking for content ideas to put up on the web-site to capture the whole roll-out process for the target audience.

Comment: As stated, I think this may be too close to the open ended questions discouraged in the FAQ. Generally speaking, if you're the only person who can evaluate the answer, the question is a bad fit for SE.  If you reformat to focus on something like "What are the critical communications during product rollout?" you might get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an entire consulting practice that focuses on these issues called Organizational Change Management.  There are methods used within this practice area that enable targeted communications to stakeholders throughout the entire change, including opening up two-way channels and ways to include stakeholders in some of the decision making and / or development...where it makes sense.  Typically, you would have a team (depending on the size and complexity of the change) come in and conduct a stakeholder analysis, which is used to identify who is out there that might be impacted, how they will be impacted, what they need to hear, what you need to hear from them, how often, and what channels.  Based on this analysis, this team would build communications and schedule delivery.  The channels could include not only a web site as you suggest but newsletters, town hall meetings, focus groups, mass e-mails, posters, postcards, and on and on.

There is a lot to this practice area.  If it is a big change, the least costly thing you could do is invest in this effort.  It's expensive...but cheap compared to the alternative of significant resistance, sabotage, or just being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

With that many unknowns I would try a Lean Startup approach where you decide on a very small MVP or value delivery, make that, and then test your ASSUMPTION that they will even use it or find value in it. You will probably fail or get a lot wrong if you just go and make something and then expect that they will see value in it because you do. Build it incrementally. Good luck.